# rails Nested Resource child and parent have same id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rails-routing

I have an Endorsement, which has_many EndorsementImage 's in my admin interface, and when i generate a link to delete the nested image, the link  uses the id of the child (which clearly doesn't work) for both itself and the parent.

You can see from my rake routes example they share the same :id ?

Any help around this would be much appreciated.

*Rake Routes example:*

```
DELETE /endorsements/:id/endorsements_images/:id(.:format)  admin/endorsements_images#destroy
```

Generates a link like this `http://foobar:3000/endorsements/8/endorsements_images/8`  --that first 8 is erroneous and should be the id of the endorsement itself, not the endorsement image.

*Routes.rb*

```
resources :endorsements do 
  member  do
    resources :endorsements_images
  end
end
```

*My Link*

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy',  admin_endorsement_images_path(@endorsement,img), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

---

Answer (score 0):

`member` block should not contain resource for endorsements_images

```
resources :endorsements do 
  member  do
    delete :endorsements_images
  end
end
```

What you are doing above is not RESTfull as `id` is already unique identifier, what I will suggest to you is to create separate resource for `endorsements_images` as you do not need endorsement_id to delete endorsements_images

```
resources :endorsements_images
```